# Use same Handlebars template for all the pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, templates, handlebars.js

I have this use-case where I would like to have one navbar for all the pages. The technique which I used until now was to keep an external JSON file and fetch it using jQuery `.getJSON` library. I was using jQuery DOM methods to generate the HTML.

That I am finding messy and would love to use Handlebars template instead. But my doubt is, in Handlebars you add script within script tag inside the HTML. So is there a way to just write an individual Handlebars template and invoke it on all the pages?

I have done some searching and couldn't find anything. I am just asking if I can embed Handlebars template like that or I do have to explicitly embed for all the pages for which I need the navbar? In other words, can I add Handlebars template inside a `xyz.js` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is: yes you can. You can either [precompile your templates](http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html) to one JavaScript file and insert them to your document with JavaScript, by using a [partial](http://handlebarsjs.com/reference.html#base-registerPartial) or with a hybrid method [such as this one by Tal Bereznitskey](http://berzniz.com/post/24743062344/handling-handlebars-js-like-a-pro), that makes it possible to mix and match precompiled and uncompiled templates.

Comment: Glad to know that it is possible and thankyou for patiently answering my question. So `precompile` is the thing I missed. I will carefully go through the links and get back to you. Thanks.